# Does Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS support AMD EPYC 7742?

Tags: 18.04

Does Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS support HPE ProLiant XL675d Gen10 Plus wiwh AMD EPYC 7742 CPU?
Thank you.

Comment: We do not provide hardware recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but probably not without some effort. That machine [has been certified for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202101-28639), though, so it may be better to go with the more recent release.